# Tomcat clustering without load balancer

Tags: java, tomcat, load-balancing

I've experimented with setting up Tomcat clustering and I was wondering if it is necessary to have a load balancer. In the [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/cluster-howto.html) they tell you that you simple need to add

```
<Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
```

to the config file to make clustering work. I've added the following default config to my instances (all on different machines, same network):

```
<Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"
             channelSendOptions="8">

      <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager"
               expireSessionsOnShutdown="false"
               notifyListenersOnReplication="true"/>

      <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">
        <Membership className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService"
                    address="228.0.0.4"
                    port="45564"
                    frequency="500"
                    dropTime="3000"/>
        <Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver"
                  address="auto"
                  port="4000"
                  autoBind="100"
                  selectorTimeout="5000"
                  maxThreads="6"/>

        <Sender className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">
          <Transport className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender"/>
        </Sender>
        <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>
        <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatchInterceptor"/>
      </Channel>

      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve"
             filter=""/>
      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve"/>

      <Deployer className="org.apache.catalina.ha.deploy.FarmWarDeployer"
                tempDir="/tmp/war-temp/"
                deployDir="/tmp/war-deploy/"
                watchDir="/tmp/war-listen/"
                watchEnabled="false"/>

      <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener"/>
    </Cluster>
```

After some testing I got the impression that the clustering is not working but before I go looking what the exact problem is I would like to know if a load balancer is necessary to make clustering work. If not then I would like to know the advantages of having one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need a load balancer. Something has to be able to direct traffic to live nodes when a node goes down. The cluster just makes sure that sessions are transferred between the nodes, so that any node can handle the requests without sessions breaking.

See the [Load Balancing](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/balancer-howto.html) chapter for some (very basic) options and details. If you wish to use a different load balancer, refer to its documentation.

Comment: So there is no leader elected in the tomcat cluster that could distribute the requests?

Comment: No, there's no automatic leader. You can configure a [Tomcat worker](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/workers.html) to act as the load balancer, but it has to be explicitly configured and doesn't share any of the other workload.

Comment: You need a load balancer for practical production conditions, but in testing it's possible to go without if you just want to test session replication

Answer (score -2):

Load balancing with clustering is a good concept for better high availability , scalability and deploying war file world wide.
for more details you can refer below link:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/cluster-howto.html

Comment: My main question is if it is necessary to use a load balancer to make it work.

Comment: Not necessary but for better performance i would suggest to use it

Comment: In case load balancer is  not implemented, requests will be entertained by the added nodes in the cluster irrespective of the load on any node. So, load distribution between the nodes will not be even and it might be case that few nodes in the cluster are handling far more requests that other nodes.

But if load balancer is implemented, requests will be served by the node under less load. So, requests will be distributed evenly between nodes in the cluster leading to high performance.